# need to created a password mismatch

Tags: java, netbeans

```
    if (jTextFieldUserName.getText() .isEmpty())
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Enter the User Name", "Dialog", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if(jTextFieldType.getText() .isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Enter the Type", "Dialog", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if(jTextFieldPassword.getText() .isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Enter the Password", "Dialog", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if(jTextFieldConfirmPassword.getText() .isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Enter the ConfirmPassword", "Dialog", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if(jTextFieldPassword.equals(jTextFieldConfirmPassword)){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Mismatch", "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    else{
    NewUser obj=new NewUser();
    obj.setUserName(jTextFieldUserName.getText());
    obj.setPassword(jTextFieldPassword.getText());
    obj.setConfirmPassword(jTextFieldConfirmPassword.getText());
    obj.setType(jTextFieldType.getText());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "New user created", "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    try{
        obj.addUsers(obj);
       } catch (Exception ex) {
       System.out.println(" "+ex.toString());
       }
    }
```

I don't know where I went wrong. I hope I have used the correct string. I am not getting the "Mismatch" and I am getting "New user created" and it is being saved to the database. Please help me out.

Comment: You have several problems. Immediately, I see that (1) you're using a *lot* of `else if` chaining, which means that your `else` probably isn't executing under the conditions you think (change the validation to a separate method instead), and (2) you're comparing the two *field controls* instead of their values.